# Is the /mnt/sdcard/Android/data folder (or equivalent) present in all hardware devices from factory?

Tags: java, android, directory, private, mkdir

I have some problems with my app on Android emulated devices because the Android/data folder (where private app folders are to be created, to be accessed with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) is not present after the device has been created and started in emulator.

I prefer not to use the mkdir command after checking if the folder exists on real users' devices for security reasons, so I hope this issue is found only in emulated devices.

Is the Android/data folder present in all real hardware devices from factory?

Comment: Of course, it is. And it's on the emulator too. Check out your AVD. Better if you delete and recreate it.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein Deleting and recreating avds for months, believe me the folder is not there

Comment: There's something wrong. Try uninstalling, reinstalling Eclipse, do all the updates (SDK and check for updates), make an emulator... It MUST be there. Select the emulator in the DDMS perspective and the /data/ folder is there.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein the /data folder is yet another thing

Answer (score 1):

All devices have an Android/data folder. But it is NOT /Android/data but something like /mnt/sdcard/Android/data or /storage/sdcard/Android/data or /storage/emulated/0/Android/data.

The /data folder is somehing completely different. It exists also on all devices.

Comment: You're right, in fact on certain avds it is under /storage/sdcard, but it is not there from the beginning.